# Java regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

Is there any way of excluding this characters: - \ _ to this pattern? I need especifically this pattern and no other

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{P}\\p{Z}]");
```

Comment: This is an excellent resources for experimenting with Regex http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use character class subtraction:

```
Pattern.compile("[\\p{P}\\p{Z}&&[^-_\\\\]]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally to exclude a character you prepend it with ^.  for example to match any number of characters that do not containt character 'a' you write:

```
[^a]*
```

Comment: so, if i want to exclude /, how would it be?